# java replacing multiple characters in a string including "\u00A2"

Tags: java, android, string, replaceall

I have a string with "Dollars" and "Cents" symbol in it. I want to remove them. I tried

```
string.replaceAll("[\"\\u00A2\" $]", "")
```

but its not working. What is the correct way to do it.

Comment: `\"\\u00A2\"` what are you trying to do here? why the quotes?

Comment: so it considers it as a char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = string.replaceAll("¢|\\$", "");
```

or

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\u00A2|\\$", "");
```

`$` is a special character in regular expressions, so you have to escape it, unless it's in a character class.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. You don't have to escape special characters inside of a set

Comment: also string.replaceAll("[\\u00A2" $]", "") works.. Thanks guys. such a stupid mistake I made =/

Comment: @Rani Be careful if you use your solution, you have a space in your character class.